# Python - Using re-sub in a loop not working

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list with movie names:
[Movie List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGsKK.png)

And another list of questions about movies:
[List of questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buFOD.png)

My objective is to loop through the list of questions and each time the function finds a name in the question that is in the list of movies, changes the name to "MOVIE".
At the moment i can do it for each question:
def remove_movie_name_1(text):

```
    for i in tqdm(range(len(movies))):
       return re.sub(movies[42], 'MOVIE', text)
remove_movie_name_1(tq[21])
```

This way i can change it for example from "What was the role played by Tim Allen in Toy Story 3?" to "What was the role played by Tim Allen in MOVIE?"

When i tried to apply it to the whole list I used this code:

```
def remove_movie_name(text):
for i in tqdm(range(len(movies))):
    return re.sub(movies[i], 'MOVIE', text)

for i in tqdm(range(len(tq))):
tq[i] = remove_movie_name(tq[i])
```

But this code doesn't change anything and I can't see what's the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_movie_name(text):
    for i in tqdm(range(len(movies))):
        return re.sub(movies[i], 'MOVIE', text)
```

`return` exits the function immediately.  Your loop only runs one time.